# Error on using weka library on android (Want to Implement Machine Learning in an Android Application)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, machine-learning, weka

For implementing Machine Learning in an Android Application, I am using 'WEKA Tool' which I have included it on the Project 'libs' and compile it from the 'gradle' of project.

But while running on the phone when that functions invoked which doing the classification (calling 'RandomForest Classifier'), my app goes crashed.

I am getting this 'Runtime Error'. Can anyone help me please?

```
   Unable to create WEKA_HOME (/wekafiles)
   Unable to create packages directory (/wekafiles/packages)
   Unable to create repository cache directory (/wekafiles/repCache)
   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: com.example.weirdmyth.testapp, PID: 31474
          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/GraphicsEnvironment;
               at weka.core.packageManagement.PackageManager.setProxyAuthentication(PackageManager.java:191)
               at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.establishWekaHome(WekaPackageManager.java:377)
               at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.<clinit>(WekaPackageManager.java:162)
               at weka.core.Utils.readProperties(Utils.java:174)
               at weka.core.Capabilities.<init>(Capabilities.java:275)
               at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.getCapabilities(AbstractClassifier.java:508)
               at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.getCapabilities(RandomTree.java:602)
               at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest.getCapabilities(RandomForest.java:182)
               at weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging.buildClassifier(Bagging.java:701)
               at com.example.weirdmyth.testapp.MainActivity.showExtractData(MainActivity.java:68)
               at com.example.weirdmyth.testapp.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:18)
               at com.example.weirdmyth.testapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4794)
               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19905)
               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-weka_24a0e957b7a2bd7b1eca884c1d1fe17134d04e02-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.0_1d91a870686be0d9b2c0cad6f095599608f8ea8b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_e60a43d4d67966d22f555860d8f3ea89bf40a00d-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_bab1238d93c9b1e214aa74253243e0e0a1179d1b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_ac3ce21dd47241b373379a2a2250d916ddec89f2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_86622e6ad735878a3262fd8fb6bc9c316447f2bd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_024d25ee6599778d6213941fb989deeaa23d0a37-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.weirdmyth.testapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-24.2.0_a300254740b0ce696848c36d6b2c7e26898aba9c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this one: https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android

As writer says: and 100% functionality is not promised.  However, it's sure better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks WekaSTRIPPED.jar from that is working for me :)